# Changing Plot order for 3D printing

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, 3d-printing

Alright, I got a my first 3D print done of a pseudosphere using parametric plot and a deflated sphere using a contour plot, but when I try

```
ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[v]*(3 - u) + .25*Sin[4 u], 
     Sin[v]*(3 - u) + .25 Sin[4 u], 
     u}, 
  {u, 6, 13}, {v, 6, 13},
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.3], FaceForm[Yellow, Blue]}, 
  PlotPoints -> {50, 50}, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All]
```

it gives an error about triangulation self-intersects. I do not have the exact error code because I'm not in charge of the MakerBot. It makes the first round and then stops.

I noticed that the estimated time was 50 times longer than it took for that first loop. Is there a way to fix that, and maybe a changing plotting order would be more machine friendly?

Comment: You mean something is wrong when you try to print it with MakerBot?

Comment: Yes, please provide more details, especially the way you exported and post-processed the plot data.

Comment: Closer inspection shows that your parametrization is generating a huge overlap which is most likely the reason for self-intersection. You need to choose `v` very carefully to generate a closed volume.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess I know what you've encountered. The model doesn't print correctly though it looks OK in *Mathematica*, right? Specifically speaking, nothing seems to be wrong when you plot the object in *Mathematica*:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[v]*(3 - u) + .25*Sin[4 u], Sin[v]*(3 - u) + .25 Sin[4 u], u}, 
{u, 6, 13}, {v, 6, 13}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.3], FaceForm[Yellow, Blue]}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

*(Notice I've changed the options a little to show that `Mesh` doesn't influence the quality of the object at all, while `PlotPoints` do influence the quality but it's not the main issue in this case. )*

And it still looks good after you export the object to a `STL` file and open it with your *MakerWare*:

[image]

But you'll find it fragmented as soon as you export it to a `X3G` file if you select *Preview before printing*:

[image]

I encountered similar issue several days ago. The reason for this error is probably mentioned [here](http://3d.about.com/od/Creating-3D-The-CG-Pipeline/ss/Preparing-A-Model-For-3d-Printing-Model-To-3d-Print-In-5-Steps.htm), you can have a look. (To be honest, I myself haven't fully understand it 囧. ) And after some communication with Makerbot Support, I think I know how to fix it now.

The easiest tool is this one:

http://cloud.netfabb.com/

Just upload your `STL` file and it'll be repaired automatically. This tool seems to be enough for your model, according to the preview:

[image]

Another choice is the *meshmixer*:

http://www.meshmixer.com/

This tool is harder to use, and I don't know how to repair your model with it right now. (According to my test, *Analysis* -> *Inspector* -> *Auto Repair All* is enough for many cases, but sadly this doesn't work for your specific model. )

So long I haven't found a way to repair models with *Mathematica* only.

---

**Edit 1**

OK… *Yves Klett* has found the way to repair your model with *Mathematica* in the comment above: just change `{v, 6, 13}` to `{v, 0, 2 Pi}` and the defect in the preview disappears.

---

**Edit 2**

I've figured out how to fix the model with *meshmixer*. What you need is just *Edit* -> *Make Solid* -> *(Modify the settings if you like)* -> *Accept*:

[image]

This time I tried to print it:

[image]

……At least the defect disappeared.

Comment: Did you mean `{v, 6, 13}` to `{v, 0, 2 Pi}`?

Comment: @YvesKlett Yeah, fixed, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the actual values and the links for mesh repair. The whole area is still a minefield and repairing complex models sometimes a true horror.

Comment: That is exactly good then. And yes, it is a nightmare. Engineering mathematics is a growing field, so I see hope.

Comment: @Teg Thanks for accepting, well, in fact you can wait for 24 hours or even more time before accepting an answer so your question may attract more and better answers :)